# B2 level requirements for English

Tags: resource-request, english, cefr

I would like to find the requirement for level B2 level (CEFR) for English. I am *mainly* interested in the grammar requirements, but also in the other requirements.

Are there any details like that?

I found the page [Complete list of B2 grammar contents](https://test-english.com/grammar-points/b2/contents-b2/) on test-english.com, but I think that is not the complete list.

Do you know a better site like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the official CEFR level descriptions at https://www.coe.int/en/web/common-european-framework-reference-languages/level-descriptions

In particular the self-assessment grid for English might be useful: https://rm.coe.int/CoERMPublicCommonSearchServices/DisplayDCTMContent?documentId=090000168045bb52

However, they do not specify that you should master certain grammatical structures, since CEFR levels are fundamentally about what you can do, not what grammar you have learned. You would have to deduce required grammar based on the vague descriptions or look for what others have done. I doubt there is an official answer.